# Saving Files with tsv Extension with a Spark DataFrameWriter

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Is it possible to save files and specify the extension with a DataFrameWriter? In the example below, I save my dataframe, using as delimiter a tab, but the output files are '.csv'.

```
my_dataframe.write.option("delimiter", "\t").csv(output_path)
```

Is there a way to specify that the extension is '.tsv'.

Comment: Have you resolved your issue please share the answer

Comment: The solution was that it can't be done with the available options. I had to do it using pathlib, using normal python statements. (s as it could be many files, depending on the number of partitions)

Answer (score -2):

[This page](http://www.legendu.net/misc/blog/spark-io-tsv/) shows how.

`output_path` needs to be a filename with a `'.tsv'` extension.

Comment: This will write data file to a folder named "f2.tsv", but the dataset file itself still have .csv extension.